# Find subsets of size K in N set

Tags: performance, algorithm, c, recursion, time-limit-exceeded

The question is: There is a set `An`, and it consists of integers from `1` to `n`.

`An={1, 2, 3, ..., n}`

Print all subsets of size `K` in `An`. It must be generated in order like the example below.

So for example, `n=5` `k=3`

`{1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 4} {1, 2, 5} {1, 3, 4} {1, 3, 5} {1, 4, 5} {2, 3, 4} ... {3, 4, 5}`

I am not sure about if there is another way that doesn't use recursion. I did this with recursion but the problem is that all test cases should be done within 1 sec. When `N` and `K` are like `5`, `3` and `12`, `6` it is okay but when it comes to like `50`, `48` or `100`, `95`, it takes too long. I am having a real struggle with this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void subset(int n, int k, int arr[], int pos[], int index, int start){
    int i, j;

    if(index == k){
        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            if(j==k-1)
                printf("%d\n", pos[j]);
            else{
                printf("%d ", pos[j]);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    for(i=start; i<n; i++){
        pos[index] = arr[i]; 
        subset(n, k, arr, pos, index+1, i+1);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, k, arr[100], index=0, start=0;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);

    // 1<=n<=100 ; 1<=k<=n
    if(n>100||n<1 && k>n||k<1)
        return 0;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i]=i+1;

    int *pos = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*k);

    time_t clockstart=0, clockend=0;
    float gap;
    clockstart = clock();
    subset(n, k, arr, pos, index, start);
    clockend = clock();
    gap = (float)(clockend-clockstart)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf("%f\n", gap);

    return 0;
}
```

I think i should use something like tail recursion or vector in C++ but I can't figure out how to work with those.

Comment: Are you sure `100, 95` is a reasonable input?  According to my calculations, you would need to output roughly 450GB in one second.  Math: \${{100}\choose{95}} * 95 * 4 = 452979912000\$, where \${100}\choose{95}\$ is the number of sets, 95 is the number of elements in each set, and 4 is the number of characters per element (2 digits plus comma plus space).  Even `50, 48` would require outputting 3.7 MB in one second, which may be difficult.

Comment: @JS1 I don't really know about the size of how much it takes. But yeah, it is possible through some other code because some people solved it.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably noticed, the slowdown happens when `n` is large and `k` is close to `n`. If it is slower than it should be, it is likely because it is doing unnecessary work. Lets have a look at the case where `n=5` and `k=3`, and go to the point in the execution of your program where `arr[0] = 1` and `index = 1`. In the `for`-loop in `subset()`, you are looking at all possible values from `start = 2` to `n = 5`. However, not all values will actually result in valid solutions. Here is a list of all `{1, i}` you check, and which subsets are possible:

```
{1, 2} -> {1, 2, 3} {1, 2, 4} {1, 2, 5}
{1, 3} -> {1, 3, 4} {1, 3, 5}
{1, 4} -> {1, 4, 5}
{1, 5} -> no solutions
```

As you can see, `{1, 5}` does not have any possible subsets. Or put otherwise, `5` is too large a number at `pos[1]` to give any solutions.

Instead of trying all numbers from `start` to `n`, try to find out what the actual maximum is that will still give solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         for(j=0; j<k; j++){
>             if(j==k-1)
>                 printf("%d\n", pos[j]);
>             else{
>                 printf("%d ", pos[j]);
>             }
>         }
> ```

KISS:

```
        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            printf("%d ", pos[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
```

---

> I am not sure about if there is another way that doesn't use recursion.

There is. If I give you a subset, how do you find the next one?

> If the last element of the subset is not the last element in `An` then increment it and return. Otherwise, if the element to its left is not the penultimate element in `An`, increment that one and extend to the right. Otherwise, ...